# Regex for not word chars slower than excluding letter ranges

Tags: javascript, regex, jsperf

http://jsperf.com/regex-not-word-selector

Why do `/\W/g` performs worse than `/[^A-Za-z]/g`?

Is it JS specific?

Comment: `\W` is not same as `[^a-zA-Z]`

Comment: Also, I see no difference in performance from your jsperf suggesting that there's something noticeable. Is there a reason you're worried about this or questioning it? The bars on that jsperf graph are pretty close. Also, if you're comparing something very specific like this regex, you should narrow down the code that you're running through each test; there's a lot of factors that could be the "cause"

Comment: I ran the test in the link and actually got it so excluding the letter range was 5% slower, not the other way around.

Comment: @Ian It's more about curiosity, because I've always thought that `\W` would perform better than a range exclusion. As you said there's no real problem with performance, I'll try to remove some code from the tests and try again to see the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

```
\w is equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_]
```

and

```
\^W is equivalent to [^A-Za-z0-9_]
```

Note that in implementations in other languages \w may or may not also match unicode characters.

The results are pretty close and in no way something I would worry about.